# Order <span> under <input>

Tags: html, css

Okay I know this problem may be super-trivial for you, but I really can not make it work. My HTML Code works right in Codepen, but when I am using that in my app template, it messes up. I have tried a lot of CSS options but none of them worked..

What my Code looks in Codepen and how it should look in my app:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNojqg

```
<div class="item range">
  <div>
  <label>1 Min.</label>
  <input id="zeitRange" name="a" type="range" min="1" max="60" value="5" step="1" oninput="showValue(this.value)" onchange="showValue(this.value)" src="controller.js">
  <label>60 Min.</label>
    </div>
  <div>
    <label>Reisezeit: </label>

  <span id="rangeValue">5</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How it actually looks in my app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OQs2.jpg

And here is my entire HTML Template:

```
<script id="templates/search.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Datenerfassung">
      <ion-content id="datenContent" scroll="true" class="has-header has-footer" ng-controller="DataCtrl">
        <div class="list">

          <div class="item item-divider">
            Bestimme deinen Startpunkt
          </div>
          <!-- Adressen Input Feld -->
           <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
             <span class="input-label">Startpunkt in Adressform</span>
             <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Startpunkt in Adressform">
           </label>
           <button id="locate" class="button button-balanced" ng-click="locate()">Aktuellen Standort verwenden</button>

           <!-- Item Divider -->
           <div class="item item-divider">
            Bestimme deine Reisezeit
           </div>
           <!-- Zeit Input Slider -->
           <div class="item range">
           <div>
            <label>1 Min.</label>
            <input id="zeitRange" name="a" type="range" min="1" max="60" value="5" step="1"
                   oninput="showValue(this.value)" onchange="showValue(this.value)" src="controller.js">
            <label>60 Min.</label>
            </div>
            <div>
            <label>Reisezeit: </label>
            <span id="rangeValue">5</span>
            </div>
          </div>


           <button id="t_button" class="button button-balanced" ng-click="set_five()">5 Min.</button>
           <button id="t_button" class="button button-balanced" ng-click="set_ten()">10 Min.</button>
           <button id="t_button" class="button button-balanced" ng-click="set_fifteen()">15 Min.</button>
           <button id="t_button" class="button button-balanced" ng-click="set_twenty()">20 Min</button>

        </div>
        <!-- Fortbewegungsmittel Toggle Liste -->
        <div class="item item-divider">
          Mit welchem Fortbewegungsmittel <br />
          möchten Sie die Umgebung erkunden?
        </div>

        <ion-radio class="radio" ng-model="$parent.move" value="walk">Zu Fuß</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio class="radio" ng-model="$parent.move" value="transit">Tram</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio class="radio" ng-model="$parent.move" value="car">Auto</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio class="radio" ng-model="$parent.move" value="bike">Fahrrad</ion-radio>

        <div class="item item-divider">
          Welche Arten von Standorten <br/> möchtest du sehen?
          </div>
        <div class="list">
          <ion-checkbox id="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in art_liste" ng-model="item.checked" ng-checked="item.checked">{{item.text}}</ion-checkbox>
          </div>

        <!-- Button zum loslegen -->
        <div style="text-align:center;">
        <button id="erkunden" ui-sref="map" class="button button-balanced" ng-Click="setData()">ReachIt!</button>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
      <ion-tabs class="tabs-balanced tabs-icon-top">
    <ion-tab ui-sref="home" title="Home" icon="ion-home"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab ui-sref="faq" title="FAQ" icon="ion-help-circled"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab ui-sref="about" title="About" icon="ion-information-circled"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab ui-sref="impressum" title="Impressum" icon="ion-clipboard"></ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
    </ion-view>
 </script>
```

I appreciate any kind of help.
Best regards, Julian

Comment: Where is the CSS code? Share a working example, with generated html instead of angular code.

Comment: I'm guessing `controller.js` is taking care of styling but isn't set up to load in the CodePen. (Also, try to maintain a level of civility. I've [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40533614/revisions) your post for language.)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I have no CSS code for the elements which cause the problem. It just contains code for the other templates. My problem is that the HTML Code displays different things in Codepen than in my app.

Ouroborus: Sorry for my immature language. I was just pretty frustrated that I cant solve that problem. In my contoller.js is no CSS involved. It just contains the javascript functions for my templates.

Comment: i think the styles are being overridden somewhere in your code base.just check it